# How and when does 'of' mean 'among'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality

> In his Commentaries on the Laws of England, William Blackstone contended that the distinction between private wrongs and crimes was:
>
> > ... As if I detain a field from another man, to which the law has given him a right, this is a civil injury, and not a crime; for here only the right of an individual is concerned, and it is immaterial to the public, **which of us** is in possession of the land: but treason, murder and robbery are properly marked among crimes; since besides the injury done to individuals, they strike at the very being of society; which cannot possibly subsist, where actions of this sort are suffered to escape with impunity.

Source: P138-139, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

User [Josh61](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/184426/50720) writes that 'of' = '`are` among'. I know that William Blackstone lived from 1723 to 1780.

1. Yet there's no verb in **which of us**? Where's the `are` from?
2. How and when does 'of' mean 'among'?
3. Is the use of **which** exceptional and rare? Is the cited explanation in that link right?

Comment: You can safely ignore Josh61's answer to the other question.

Comment: As so often happens with your questions, you select an archaic text, then ask us to propose direct replacement "synonyms" for text elements which are intrinsically linked to ***idiomatic syntax*** (which changes over time). In your example context it's possible to say ***of*** could be replaced by ***among*** (or ***which of us*** could be replaced by ***who***, for example). But this probably won't help you to understand what the original words mean in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Answering these out of order:

"Of" can mean "among" when it refers to a set (plurality) of nouns. In this case, "us" refers to the set ["I", "another man"].  It does not matter to the public which among [this set] is in possession of the land.

Your inclusion of the word "are" is divorced from the context of Josh61's statement; in his sentence it *does* make sense, but that does not mean that you would include "are" here.

> *which of us* refers to [those who are] [among us] ( in possession of the land).

In other words, "are" is used in its infinitive sense of "to exist".

> "... refers to [those who exist within the set] [us]."

I would actually argue that Josh61's conclusion (in your linked question/answer) is wrong - this seems to match the very first, standard definition of "which".  From a set, you are identifying a particular one. In other words, from ["I", "another man"], only one can be in possession of the land.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Would you please identify 'his'  in your last paragraph? Whose conclusion is wrong? Also, would you please explain [this set] in your 2nd paragraph? I'm confused; how does it "not matter which among [a set of random people] is in possession of the land"?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: @LePressentiment - I modified the last paragraph, but I'm not sure that editing the second paragraph will resolve anything. I was referring back to the sentence you originally posted. "...it is immaterial to the public, which of us is in possession of the land..." This phrase means exactly what I posted - to the public, it does not matter whether ["I"] or ["another man"] - the members of the set previously defined - are in possession of the land. This is purely a civil matter between the two set members.